# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Updating of environment hangs forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, error-handling, compiler-errors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just tried to update my environment, but since a day it seems like the environment is stuck in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS.

Can't update the environment again:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:... is in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS state and can not be updated.

Nor is it possible to delete the environment:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack [arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:.. cannot be deleted while in status UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS

Anybody experienced the same issue?
Basically just one rebuild the old version. The old version was running for month...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get into the log files:
/var/log/eb-activity.log
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
/var/log/eb-version-deployment.log

Answer (score 3):

Go to cloud formation, identify your project template with status UPDATA_IN_PROGRESS and cancel it. After that you can delete every thing on your elastic beanstalk console and start over if you want

Comment: [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=789775); [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/delete-application.html)